# Is there a way to run Boto3 (AWS SDK) command in Github Actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, github-actions

I want to run some Boto3 commands in Github Actions instead of AWS CLI command. I can install python but not sure about pip3 and Boto3.

Could you share some documents or guide me the process? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run it on your local linux or mac machine, you can most likely run it on GitHub Actions.

There is no need to install python or pip - they are already available on the GitHub hosted runner. All you need to do, is install Boto3 (or anything else you need that is not already pre-installed).

You can see which tools are installed on the GitHub runners in [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/specifications-for-github-hosted-runners#supported-software).